# Get the last 12 months in PHP

Tags: php, date

So here is an interesting problem I learned today.

I need to populate an array with the last 12 months, starting with the past month. So in August 2011, the last 12 months will be Sep 2010 - July 2011. To do this, I am using:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
    $months[] = date("Y-m%", strtotime("-$i months"));
```

The code above works just fine on August 30. I get the last 12 months:

```
array
    0 => string '2011-07%' (length=8)
    1 => string '2011-06%' (length=8)
    2 => string '2011-05%' (length=8)
    3 => string '2011-04%' (length=8)
    4 => string '2011-03%' (length=8)
    5 => string '2011-02%' (length=8)
    6 => string '2011-01%' (length=8)
    7 => string '2010-12%' (length=8)
    8 => string '2010-11%' (length=8)
    9 => string '2010-10%' (length=8)
    10 => string '2010-09%' (length=8)
    11 => string '2010-08%' (length=8)
```

But when I run this on Aug 31, I get:

```
array
    0 => string '2011-07%' (length=8)
    1 => string '2011-07%' (length=8)
    2 => string '2011-05%' (length=8)
    3 => string '2011-05%' (length=8)
    4 => string '2011-03%' (length=8)
    5 => string '2011-03%' (length=8)
    6 => string '2011-01%' (length=8)
    7 => string '2010-12%' (length=8)
    8 => string '2010-12%' (length=8)
    9 => string '2010-10%' (length=8)
    10 => string '2010-10%' (length=8)
    11 => string '2010-08%' (length=8)
```

I have tried both Windows and Unix. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I'm sure someone has a more elegant solution, but you could start counting backwards from the 1st of this month.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("Y-m%", strtotime( date( 'Y-m-01' )." -$i months"));
}
```

Comment: I think the 'first of the month' thing is pretty necessary unless crack out some insane PHP library function (which I don't even want to do for a one line loop) and the fact that it uses well known functions in three lines very readably is what I think makes this solution a brilliant one, merci!

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to propose an alternative solution using [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/) instead.

There are a number of caveats to watch out for here. For one, you don't want things like **Timezone** information, or **day**/**time** information to get in your way. You're only interested in the month. So we can normalize some of this information to prevent complications like overflows and daylight savings complications, etc... Since you *could* easily fall into this trap only on specific dates/times when these rare events occur.

```
$start = new DateTime;
$start->setDate($start->format('Y'), $start->format('n'), 1); // Normalize the day to 1
$start->setTime(0, 0, 0); // Normalize time to midnight
$start->sub(new DateInterval('P12M'));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$recurrences = 12;

foreach (new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $recurrences, true) as $date) {
    echo $date->format('F, Y'), "\n"; // attempting to make it more clear to read here
}
```

Output:

```
February, 2019
March, 2019
April, 2019
May, 2019
June, 2019
July, 2019
August, 2019
September, 2019
October, 2019
November, 2019
December, 2019
January, 2020
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is more elegant and robust than the accepted one. I think it should be upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

It's because not every month has a 31st. So `strtotime()` is advancing to the next month. i.e.  4/31 = 5/1.

You'd be better off using `mktime()` for this as it's *dumber* than `strtotime()`.

#### UPDATE

To take advantage of a *smart* function like `strtotime()` and avoid tracking the year for `mktime()`, the following is my suggestion:

```
$month = time();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
  $month = strtotime('last month', $month);
  $months[] = date("r", $month);
}
print_r($months);
```

Adjust logic and optimize as you see fit.

Comment: This seems to be obvious. But why does it work in the first example for February (only 28 days) as well?

Comment: Scratch that. The first example is inaccurate. I don't get that for 8/30. I get two Marches.

Comment: No, +1 month is not 30 days. Your first explanation was correct, it just increases the 'month digit' and overflows to the first day in the next month.

Comment: If someone wants to generate future months, replace "last month" with "next month". using these last and next words will accurately give last and next months respectively. using "+" or "-" signs are complicated since it adds or reduces 30 days while all months are not having 30 days equally. That is in February, it happens to be a wrong option.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
$this_month = date("n", time());
$this_year = date("Y", time());
$months_array = array();
for ($i = $this_month - 1; $i > ($this_month - 13); $i--) {
    echo "$i<br>";
    if ($i < 1) {
        $correct_month_number = $i + 12;
        $months_array[] = array($correct_month_number, $this_year - 1);
    }
    else {
        $months_array[] = array($i, $this_year);
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($months_array); echo "</pre>";
```

The data types are a little loose, but this gets the job done. The nice thing about this is that it only calls the date() function for the current month and year, once. The rest of the logic is just simple math. No need to worry about the length of each month.

Then you can use the $months_array array to build whatever you need.

Answer (score -4):

The joys of different month lengths. strtotime is being literally, and taking 'Aug 31' and tryinn to make "Sep 31", which doesn't exist. So you end up with Oct 1 or something. A safer approach is this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("Y-m%", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2011));
}
```

strtotime is magical sometimes, but it's not reliable and certainly not "fast".

Comment: What happens when year becomes 2012? change mktime(.,.,.,.,.,date('Y')) ?

Comment: yes, if you need this to adjust to the current year at all times.

Comment: Still doesn't work if last 12 months spans over 2 years as in the example. (i.e. 2011 - 2010)