# Removing months in a year

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a loop to show the last 12 months, but March appears twice.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 12; $i++) {

   $month = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("now -$i month"));

   echo "$month<br>";

}
```

Output:

```
30/01/2020
30/12/2019
30/11/2019
30/10/2019
30/09/2019
30/08/2019
30/07/2019
30/06/2019
30/05/2019
30/04/2019
30/03/2019
02/03/2019
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: February doesn't have the 30th day. What do you expect here?

Comment: Where do you see March appearing twice?

Comment: @Sherif, `28.02 + 2days => 02.03`. At the end https://3v4l.org/D3Hsr

Comment: I am removing a month, not 30 days.

Comment: @JeffersonHillebrecht, it thinks that the day number will be the same and month is decreasing only. Today is 30, for 02 month 30 is 28+2. Tomorrow will be a very interesting result) 31)) If you need to avoid it - make some check for a new value of the month.

Comment: Perhaps you should see this question and answer. This may be same solution for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262971/get-the-last-12-months-in-php/7263023

Comment: @AksenP I got it, thanks.

Comment: Need to know what your expected output is, we can help you with your code but we can't invent a 30th of February

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first day of the month as the basis in your script.

```
"first day of this month -$i month"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod) for this task and not `date`. It's much simpler and more sane.

```
$start = new DateTime;
$start->setDate($start->format('Y'), $start->format('n'), 1); // Normalize the day to 1
$start->sub(new DateInterval('P12M'));
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$recurrences = 12;

foreach (new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $recurrences, true) as $date) {
    echo $date->format('F, Y'), "\n"; // attempting to make it more clear to read here
}
```

Output:

```
February, 2019
March, 2019
April, 2019
May, 2019
June, 2019
July, 2019
August, 2019
September, 2019
October, 2019
November, 2019
December, 2019
January, 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime and keep track of month/year combinations that you already had:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$previous = [];
for ($i=0; $i < 12; $i++) {

    $month = $dt->format("d/m/Y");
    echo "$month<br>".PHP_EOL;
    $previous[$dt->format('Y-m')] = true;
    $dt->modify('-1 month');
    while (array_key_exists($dt->format('Y-m'), $previous)) {
        $dt->modify('-1 day');
    }

}
```

If this encounters a previously encountered month-year combination, it starts substracting days until it reaches the previous month.
Will produce this output:

```
30/01/2020
30/12/2019
30/11/2019
30/10/2019
30/09/2019
30/08/2019
30/07/2019
30/06/2019
30/05/2019
30/04/2019
30/03/2019
28/02/2019
```